# How to adjust the space between pictures using minipage?

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment

I use minipages to place three graphs, however the spaces between each two is not with the same width. Here is the code, may someone help me? and how to locate the (a) (b) (c) above the each of the graph?

```
    \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{
    shapes.geometric,
    positioning,
    fit,
    calc
}
\usepackage{scalefnt}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\hspace{-4mm}
\begin{minipage}{0.33\linewidth}
\centering
%\includegraphics[width=2.3in]{image/CompositionalStucture}
(a)
\tikzset{
 block/.style = {circle, draw,align=center,inner sep=0pt},
 line/.style = {draw,->},
 }
{\scalefont{0.8}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=15mm]
\node[block,minimum size=6mm] (s2) {1};
\node[block,right of =s2,anchor=center,minimum size=4mm] (s3){2};
\node[block, right of=s2,anchor=center,,minimum size=6mm] (s4) {};

\path[line] (-0.8,0)-- (s2){};
\path[line] (s2)-- node[above]{Err}(s4);
\path[line] (s2) to [out=120,in=40,looseness=5] node[above] {$\Sigma$/Err}(s2);
\path[line] (s4) to [out=120,in=40,looseness=5]node[above] {$\Sigma$}(s4);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
%\red{2}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.33\linewidth}
\centering
%\includegraphics[width=2.3in]{image/CompositionalStucture}
(b)
\tikzset{
 block/.style = {circle, draw,align=center,inner sep=0pt},
 line/.style = {draw,->},
 }
{\scalefont{0.8}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=15mm]
\node[block,minimum size=6mm](s2) {1};
\node[block,right of =s2,anchor=center,minimum size=4mm] (s3){2};
\node[block, right of=s2,anchor=center,minimum size=6mm] (s4) {};

\path[line] (-0.8,0)-- (s2){};
\path[line] (s2)-- node[above]{ru}(s4);
\path[line] (s2) to [out=120,in=40,looseness=5] node[above] {$\Sigma$/ru}(s2);
\path[line] (s4) to [out=120,in=40,looseness=5]node[above] {$\Sigma$}(s4);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
%\red{3}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.33\linewidth}
\centering
%\includegraphics[width=2.3in]{image/CompositionalStucture}
(c)
\tikzset{
 block/.style = {ellipse, draw,align=center,inner sep=0pt},
 line/.style = {draw,->},
 }
{\scalefont{0.8}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=10mm]
\node[align=center](s1) {\ldots};
\node[block,minimum size=3.5mm,below of =s1](s5) {(19,1)};
\node[block,minimum size=3.5mm,below of = s5](s6) {(20,2)};

\path[line] (s1)-- (s5);
\path[line] (s5)-- node[right]{ru}(s6);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
%\red{3}
\end{minipage}
\caption{Monitoring Automata}
\label{fig:monitoringAutomata}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please, try to use the proper tags for your questions: not always you have to use the combination [tag:tikz-pgf],[tag:tikz-styles],[tag:tikz-trees].

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino sorry. Thanks for editing and reminder, I will take it care next time

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3):

The reason of the different spaces are linked to the use of `minipage`: you define blocks of fixed width and your picture inside these blocks does not fill the whole blocks, leaving different empty spaces. You can see them if you put your minipages in an `\fbox{...}` block.

[image]

You may better take a look at the [subcaption package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/subcaption), or position manually the spaces using `\hspace{dimension}` like that:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
% picture A
\end{tikzpicture}
\hspace{5mm}
\begin{tikzpicture}
% picture B
\end{tikzpicture}
```

**Edit: usage of subcaption package**

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{
    shapes.geometric,
    positioning,
    fit,
    calc
}
\usepackage{scalefnt}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
    \subcaptionbox{}{
        \tikzset{
             block/.style = {circle, draw,align=center,inner sep=0pt},
             line/.style = {draw,->},
         }
        \scalefont{0.8}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=15mm]
            \node[block,minimum size=6mm] (s2) {1};
            \node[block,right of =s2,anchor=center,minimum size=4mm] (s3){2};
            \node[block, right of=s2,anchor=center,,minimum size=6mm] (s4) {};

            \path[line] (-0.8,0)-- (s2){};
            \path[line] (s2)-- node[above]{Err}(s4);
            \path[line] (s2) to [out=120,in=40,looseness=5] node[above] {$\Sigma$/Err}(s2);
            \path[line] (s4) to [out=120,in=40,looseness=5]node[above] {$\Sigma$}(s4);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
    \subcaptionbox{}{
        \tikzset{
             block/.style = {circle, draw,align=center,inner sep=0pt},
             line/.style = {draw,->},
         }
        \scalefont{0.8}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=15mm]
            \node[block,minimum size=6mm](s2) {1};
            \node[block,right of =s2,anchor=center,minimum size=4mm] (s3){2};
            \node[block, right of=s2,anchor=center,minimum size=6mm] (s4) {};

            \path[line] (-0.8,0)-- (s2){};
            \path[line] (s2)-- node[above]{ru}(s4);
            \path[line] (s2) to [out=120,in=40,looseness=5] node[above] {$\Sigma$/ru}(s2);
            \path[line] (s4) to [out=120,in=40,looseness=5]node[above] {$\Sigma$}(s4);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
    \subcaptionbox{}{
        \tikzset{
             block/.style = {ellipse, draw,align=center,inner sep=0pt},
             line/.style = {draw,->},
         }
        \scalefont{0.8}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=10mm]
            \node[align=center](s1) {\ldots};
            \node[block,minimum size=3.5mm,below of =s1](s5) {(19,1)};
            \node[block,minimum size=3.5mm,below of = s5](s6) {(20,2)};

            \path[line] (s1)-- (s5);
            \path[line] (s5)-- node[right]{ru}(s6);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
    \caption{Monitoring Automata}
    \label{fig:monitoringAutomata}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

** Edit 2:**
To put all the picture in the same row, you could use `\resizebox{width}{height}{box}`.
On the below example, I have rescaled the middle picture to demonstrate the use of the command.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usetikzlibrary{
    shapes.geometric,
    positioning,
    fit,
    calc
}
\usepackage{scalefnt}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{%
    \subcaptionbox{}{%
        \tikzset{
             block/.style = {circle, draw,align=center,inner sep=0pt},
             line/.style = {draw,->},
        }
        \scalefont{0.8}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=15mm]
            \node[block,minimum size=6mm] (s2) {1};
            \node[block,right of =s2,anchor=center,minimum size=4mm] (s3){2};
            \node[block, right of=s2,anchor=center,,minimum size=6mm] (s4) {};

            \path[line] (-0.8,0)-- (s2){};
            \path[line] (s2)-- node[above]{Err}(s4);
            \path[line] (s2) to [out=120,in=40,looseness=5] node[above] {$\Sigma$/Err}(s2);
            \path[line] (s4) to [out=120,in=40,looseness=5]node[above] {$\Sigma$}(s4);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
    \subcaptionbox{}{\scalebox{4}{% For demonstration purpose!
        \tikzset{
             block/.style = {circle, draw,align=center,inner sep=0pt},
             line/.style = {draw,->},
        }
        \scalefont{0.8}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=15mm]
            \node[block,minimum size=6mm](s2) {1};
            \node[block,right of =s2,anchor=center,minimum size=4mm] (s3){2};
            \node[block, right of=s2,anchor=center,minimum size=6mm] (s4) {};

            \path[line] (-0.8,0)-- (s2){};
            \path[line] (s2)-- node[above]{ru}(s4);
            \path[line] (s2) to [out=120,in=40,looseness=5] node[above] {$\Sigma$/ru}(s2);
            \path[line] (s4) to [out=120,in=40,looseness=5]node[above] {$\Sigma$}(s4);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }}
    \subcaptionbox{}{%
        \tikzset{
             block/.style = {ellipse, draw,align=center,inner sep=0pt},
             line/.style = {draw,->},
         }
        \scalefont{0.8}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=10mm]
            \node[align=center](s1) {\ldots};
            \node[block,minimum size=3.5mm,below of =s1](s5) {(19,1)};
            \node[block,minimum size=3.5mm,below of = s5](s6) {(20,2)};

            \path[line] (s1)-- (s5);
            \path[line] (s5)-- node[right]{ru}(s6);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
    } % resizebox
    \caption{Monitoring Automata}
    \label{fig:monitoringAutomata}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

*Note:* ! as height means "calculate the height to keep the aspect ratio"

[image]

Comment: thanks, however, when I use the subcaption package, only two display at the same line, the third graph is below of the first two, may I know how to reduce the space so that three graphs can display at the same line?

Comment: use `\resizebox{width}{height}{box}`, see my 2nd edit